# What pins to use on a Teensy to get data from multiple peripherals?

Tags: library, pins, gps, teensy, imu

I'm using a Teensy to keep records on the location, speed, altitude, and direction of a weather balloon I'm hoping to launch. I have an Adafruit LSM9DS1 and a Ublox NEO-M8N with compass (HMC5833L) so to get all the data from these I need to connect to a total of 6 pins to get the data. I also want to use a Pixhawk radio telemetry unit to send these data to the ground so I can see them in realtime, so that will involve at least 2 more pins I believe.

The Teensy appears to have plenty of IO pins for all of this, but I've noticed that in all the libraries I've installed to try to use with these things, the pins to use aren't explicitly set. The libraries I've played with include the Adafruit LSM9DS1 library, NeoGPS, Pixhawk Arduino link, RadioHead, Grove HMC5833L, and others. I've been able to get some serial data in by using pins 18 and 19, but I can't attach all the periperhals to the same pin.

It feels like I'm missing something very basic here but I haven't been able to figure out how to use these libraries with inputs on different pins. Even when I look into the code of the libraries themselves, I can't find where the pins are being set. Most of the documentation that mentions which pins things use is written for specific Arduino models, like the Uno, and don't mention the Teensy.

What pins do I use if I want to read and write on more than one peripheral from my Teensy? How can I get data on more than just the two "default pins" that these libraries seem to expect?

Comment: You need to look at each device/library, there is no standard for changing default pins. You might not even need to change them for e.g. I2C where several peripherals can be on the same bus if no address conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to look at when determining which pins to connect a peripheral to is what protocol that peripheral uses - e.g. I2C, SPI, analog voltage via ADC, etc. The Teensy pinout for the version you have (e.g. [the 3.2 pinout](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy32.html#pins)) lists which pins can function as which protocol functions. For example, pin 19 can act as an analog input (`A5`) or as part of the 0th I2C unit, `SCL0`. Your `LSM9DS1` can use I2C, so you could connect it to that I2C unit. Typically Arduino libraries will default to using the default peripheral type. In Arduino, an I2C bus is called `Wire`, so a library for an I2C device will typically use the `Wire` device. Well-written libraries will also let you pass in your own peripheral, which is how you change the pins. Each library will do this differently.